# What's the difference between array and &array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Assume that

```
int array[16];
```

There is standard conversion called array-to-pointer conversion, so `array` would be converted implicitly to type `int*`,  but why `&array` is equal to `array`?

For instance,

```
int array[16];
void *p = array;
void *q = &array;
printf("%p\n", p);
printf("%p\n", q);
```

This will give out the same address and no compiling error.

Why?

Comment: You can also check this link : https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-array-and-array-for-int-array5/amp/

Answer (score 22):

The type of `&array` is `int (*)[16]` (a pointer to an array of 16 integers). The type of `array`, when left to decay, is `int*` (a pointer to an integer). They both point to the same location, but have a different meaning to the compiler.

If you do `(&array)[0]`, the value you end up with is the original array of 16 integers, that you can subscript again, like `(&array)[0][0]`. `(&array)[1]` would be the next array of 16 integers, if there was one.

If you do `array[0]`, the value you end up with is an integer, which you can't subscript again. `array[1]` is just the next integer. (This is true regardless of if `array` is a `int[16]` or a `int*`.)

Obviously, if you then turn your pointers into `void` pointers, you lose any semantic difference there could have been.

Answer (score 10):

That is how *array names* behave in `C`.

The name of the array variable represents the address of the first element of the array.

so,

```
void *p = array;   //array name, gives address of the  first element.
```

and

```
void *q = &array;  //adress-of-array name, also gives address of the first element
                   // actually &array is of type int (*)[16] which is decayed to int * 
                   // and casted to void * here
```

**P.S.** Even, FWIW,

```
 void *r = &array[0]; //address of the first element
```

will also give you the same address.

> *This will give out the same address and no compiling error.*

They are indeed same value, and here compiler has nothing to *scream* about.

Point to note: once you assign the address(es) to a void pointer, you'll lose the *type* information associated with them.

Comment: Is `void *q = &array` even totally valid given `&array` is of type `int(*)`?

Answer (score -1):

An array in C behaves as a pointer to the address of the first element in memory.

Comment: Not entirely true. In most cases, an array name decays into a pointer to the first element in the array, but take this example: `char foo[20] = "bar"; size_t size = sizeof foo;`, if `foo` would be a pointer, `size` would be 4 or 8, but in fact it will be 20

Answer (score -2):

Because you're basically saying the same thing in these two lines:

```
void *p = array; // Pointer to array, which is an address
void *q = &array; // Pointer to reference to an array, which is basically saying "A pointer to the same address as the pointer".
```

In other words:

```
void *p;
```

Is the same as:

```
&array;
```