# unable to insert element into linked list

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that finds all the `")"` in an expression and puts them in a linked list, always adding at the beginning of the list. The problem is that when I try to place a new element into the list, the program stops working.

With a sample user input `865)987`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element {
    char data;
    struct element *next;
} ELEMENT;


int main(void)
{
   ELEMENT *first = NULL;
   ELEMENT *new_a;

   char input[30];
   int x=0;

   printf("Input expression: ");
   scanf("%s", &input);

   while(input[x]!='\0'){
       if (input[x]==')'){
           printf("%c", input[x]);        //This works just fine.
           new_a->data = input[x];        //Here, the program stops working.
           new_a->next = first;
           first = new_a;
       }
       x++;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

```
new_a->data
```

is equivalent to

```
(*new_a).data
```

As you can see, `new_a` is attempted to be dereferenced. The problem is that `new_a` is **uninitialized**, so any subsequent attempt to dereference it is **undefined behavior** (in shape of, e.g., a segmentation fault).

In order to fix this, you need to allocate memory for `new_a`:

1. **Allocate space on the stack.** This will only work if the linked list is exclusively used in `main` because local variables' scope [only embraces the beginning and end of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable).
   Do it like this:

   ```
   ELEMENT new_a;

   ...

   new_a.data = input[x];
   new_a.next = first;
   first = &new_a;
   ```
2. **Use [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).** This is usually used for linked lists and is applicable for a linked list existing till the very termination of your program because it's scope-independent:

   ```
   ELEMENT* new_a = malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
   ```

   **Don't forget to [`free`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) afterwards!**

---

Notes:

- [Passing `input` to `scanf` suffices;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194630/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-array) no need for `&input`.
- Your `scanf` is vulnerable to buffer overflows. Use

  ```
  scanf("%s29", input);
  ```

  instead. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c) also.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it seems to be working! Just a minor problem: There is a new warning on the line with "first = &new_a;", "assignment from incompatible pointer type". Do you happen to know why that is?

Comment: @DerekT **Either** allocate on the stack with `ELEMENT new_a;` **(note the lack of the asterisk!)** and use `first = &new_a;` **or** allocate on the free store with `malloc` and use `first = new_a;`. Or is it something else? If your issue isn't fixed, *add the error message*, please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for `new_a`:

```
new_a = malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, the correct code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element {
    char data;
    struct element *next;
} ELEMENT;

int main(void)
{
    ELEMENT *first = NULL;  
    char input[30];
    int x=0;

    printf("Input expression: ");
    scanf("%s", &input);

    while(input[x]!='\0'){
        if (input[x]==')'){
            ELEMENT *new_a = (ELEMENT*)malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
            printf("%c", input[x]);
            new_a->data = input[x];
            new_a->next = first;
            first = new_a;
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: scanf("%s", &input); should be scanf("%s", input);, dont need to cast malloc return value. and for consistency should have return 0 in main

Comment: @amdixon Of cause, you're right! But I just copy athor code and fix error of adding nodes to list. However, I think that cast return value of malloc better then don't do it.