# Multiplying integer with elements of pointer array in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *parray;
    *parray=&array;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d%d",*(parray[i]*2));// [Error] invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
    }
    getch();
}
```

I don't know why this error is coming. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *parray;
*parray=&array;
```

**1.** `parray` is of type `int *` and in next line when you dereference it (*undefined behaviour* as it is uninitialized) becomes type `int` to which you try to assign address of array . Just do -

```
parray=array;
```

**2.** And in this line -

```
  printf("%d%d",*(parray[i]*2));  //gave 2 specifiers but pass one argument ??
```

You use 2 format specifiers but you pass only one argument and that also of wrong type.

When you write `parray[i]` it means `*(parray+i)` ,you don't need to further dereference it using `*` , as it already of type `int` (*and you try to dereference an* `int` variable).

Just writing this would work-

```
printf("%d",parray[i]*2);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. This line

   ```
   *parray=&array;
   ```

   is **undefined behavior** because `parray` hasn't been initialized. Dereferencing it will point to an **indeterminate memory location**.
   Use

   ```
   parray = array;
   ```

   instead. Read up on [the difference between `array` and `&array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194630/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-array) also.
2. This expression

   ```
   *(parray[i] * 2)
   ```

   causes your compilation error. Applying the subscript operator to an `int*` (`parray`) yields an `int`. Multiplying that by `2` yields an `int` again. Now you attempt to dereference that `int`. `int` is **no pointer**, so **it cannot be dereferenced**.

   The format specifier `%d%d` expects **two** `int`s. You only provide **one**, so this is undefined behavior again. A simple `%d` suffices.

   **After all**, change

   ```
   printf("%d%d",*(parray[i]*2));
   ```

   to

   ```
   printf("%d", parray[i] * 2);
   ```