# Where is the address to the first element of an array stored?

Tags: c, arrays

I was playing with C, and I just discovered that a and &a yield to the same result that is the address to the first element of the array. By surfing here over the topics, I discovered they are only formatted in a different way. So my question is: where is this address stored?

Comment: It might not be stored *anywhere*. If the array is a local array - on the stack - its address will be computed as an offset to the stack pointer.

Comment: While both a and &a  print the same thing, `&a` is address of the array, a pointer to the array, while `a` is pointer to the first element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between array and &array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194630/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-array)

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) -- on access (subject to the 4-exceptions listed [3-in C 2018]), an array is converted to a pointer to its first element. A pointer is nothing but a normal variable that stores the memory address where something else can be found. The address of the first element is stored in the pointer used to reference an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question! The answer will depend on the specifics of the hardware you're working with and what C compiler you have.

From the perspective of the C language, each object has an address, but there's no specific prescribed mechanism that accounts for how that address would actually be stored or accessed. That's left up to the compiler to decide.

Let's imagine that you've declared your array as a local variable, and then write something like `array[137]`, which accesses the 137th element of the array. How does the generated program know how to find your array? On most systems, the CPU has a dedicated register called the *stack pointer* that keeps track of the position of the memory used for all the local variables of the current function. As the compiler translates your C code into an actual executable file, it maintains an internal table mapping each local variable to some offset away from where the stack pointer points. For example, it might say something like "because 64 bytes are already used up for other local variables in this function, I'm going to place `array` 64 bytes past where the stack pointer points." Then, whenever you reference `array`, the compiler generates machine instructions of the form "look 64 bytes past the stack pointer to find the array."

Now, imagine you write code like this:

```
printf("%p\n", array); // Print address of array
```

How does the compiler generate code for this? Well, internally, it knows that array is 64 bytes past the stack pointer, so it might generate code of the form "add 64 to the stack pointer, then pass that as an argument to `printf`."

So in that sense, the answer to your question could be something like "the hardware stores a single pointer called the stack pointer, and the generated code is written in a way that takes that stack pointer and then adds some value to it to get to the point in memory where the array lives."

Of course, there are a bunch of caveats here. For example, some systems have both a *stack pointer* and a *frame pointer*. Interpreters use a totally different strategy and maintain internal data structures tracking where everything is. And if the array is stored at global scope, there's a different mechanism used altogether.

Hope thi shelps!

Answer (score 2):

It isn't stored anywhere - it's computed as necessary.

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

When you declare an array like

```
T a[N];  // for any non-function type T
```

what you get in memory is

```
+---+
|   | a[0]
+---+
|   | a[1]
+---+
 ...
+---+ 
|   | a[N-1]
+---+
```

That's it.  No storage is materialized for any pointer.  Instead, whenever you use `a` in any expression, the compiler will compute the address of `a[0]` and use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this C code:

```
int x;

void foo(void)
{
    int y;
    ...
}
```

When implementing this program, a C compiler will need to generate instructions that access the `int` objects named `x` and `y` and the `int` object allocated by the `malloc`. How does it tell those instructions where the objects are?

Each processor architecture has some way of referring to data in memory. This includes:

- The machine instruction includes some bits that identify a processor register. The address in memory is in that processor register.
- The machine instruction includes some bits that specify an address.
- The machine instruction includes some bits that specify a processor register and some bits that specify an offset or displacement.

So, the compiler has a way of giving an address to the processor. It still needs to know that address. How does it do that?

One way is the compiler could decide exactly where everything in memory is going to go. It could decide it is going to put all the program’s instructions at addresses 0 to 10,000, and it is going to put data at 10,000 and on, and that `x` will go at address 12300. Then it could write an instruction to fetch `x` from address 12300. This is called absolute addressing, and it is rarely used anymore because it is inflexible.

Another option is that the compiler can let the program loader decide where to put the data. When the software that loads the program into memory is running, it will read the executable, see how much space is needed for instructions, how much is needed for data that is initialized to zero, how much space is needed for data with initial values listed in the executable file, how much space is needed for data that does not need to be initialized, how much space is requested for the stack, and so on. Then the loader will decide where to put all of these things. As it does so, it will set some processor registers, or some tables in memory, to contain the addresses where things go.

In this case, the compiler may know that `x` goes at displacement 2300 from the start of the “zero-initialized data” section, and that the loader sets register r12 to contain the base address of that section. Then, when the compiler wants to access `x`, it will generate an instruction that says “Use register r12 plus the displacement 2300.” This is largely the method used today, although there are many embellishments involving linking multiple object modules together, leaving a placeholder in the object module for the name `x` that the linker or loader fills in with the actual displacement as they do their work, and other features.

In the case of `y`, we have another problem. There can be two or more instances of `y` existing at once. The function `foo` might call itself, which causes there to be a `y` for the first call and a different `y` for the second call. Or `foo` might call another function that calls `foo`. To deal with this, most C implementations use a stack. One register in the processor is chosen to be a stack pointer. The loader allocates a large amount of space and sets the stack pointer register to point to the “top” of the space (usually the high-address end, but this is arbitrary). When a function is called, the stack pointer is adjusted according to how much space the new function needs for its local data. When the function executes, it puts all of its local data in memory locations determined by the value of the stack pointer when the function started executing.

In this model, the compiler knows that the `y` for the current function call is at a particular offset relative to the current stack pointer, so it can access `y` using instructions with addresses such as “the contents of the stack pointer plus 84 bytes.” (This can be done with a stack pointer alone, but often we also have a frame pointer, which is a copy of the stack pointer at the moment the function was called. This provides a firmer base address for working with local data, one that might not change as much as the stack pointer does.)

In either of these models, the compiler deals with the address of an array the same way it deals with the address of a single `int`: It knows where the object is stored, relative to some base address for its data segment or stack frame, and it generates the same sorts of instruction addressing forms.

Beyond that, when you access an array, such as `a[i]`, or possibly a multidimensional array, `a[i][j][k]`, the compiler has to do more calculations. To do this, compiler takes the starting address of the array and does the arithmetic necessary to add the offsets for each of the subscripts. Many processors have instructions that help with these calculations—a processor may have an addressing form that says “Take a base address from one register, add a fixed offset, and add the contents of another register multiplied by a fixed size.” This will help access arrays of one dimension. For multiple dimensions, the compiler has to write extra instructions to do some of the calculations.

If, instead of using an array element, like `a[i]`, you take its address, as with `&a[i]`, the compiler handles it similarly. It will get a base address from some register (the base address for the data segment or the current stack pointer or frame pointer), add the offset to where `a` is in that segment, and then add the offset required for `i` elements. All of the knowledge of where `a[i]` is is built into the instructions the compiler writes, plus the registers that help manage the program’s memory layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yet one more point of view, a TL;DR answer if you will: When the compiler produces the binary, it stores the address *everywhere where it is needed* in the generated machine code.

The address may be just plain number in the machine code, or it may be a calculation of some sort, such as "stack frame base address register + a fixed offset number",  but in either case it is duplicated everywhere in the machine code where it is needed.

In other words, it is not stored in any one location. Talking more technically, `&some_array` is not an *lvalue*, and trying to take the address of it, `&(&some_array)`, will produce compiler error.

This actually applies to all variables, array is not special in any way here. The address of a variable can be used in the machine code directly (and if compiler actually generates code which does store the address somewhere, you have no way to know that from C code, you have to look at the assembly code).

The one thing special about arrays, which seems to be the source of your confusion is, that `some_array` is bascially a more convenient syntax for `&(some_array[0])`, while `&some_array` means something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it:

The address of the first element doesn't have to be stored anywhere.

An array is a chunk of memory.  It ***has*** an address simply because it exists somewhere in memory.  That address may or may not have to be stored somewhere depending on a lot of things that others have already mentioned.

Asking where the address of the array has to be stored is like asking where reality stores the location of your car.  The location doesn't have to be stored - your car is located where your car happens to ***be*** - it's a property of existing.  Sure, you can make a note that you parked your car in row 97, spot 114 of some huge lot, but you don't have to.  And your car will be wherever it is regardless of your note-taking.