# Order of precedence in C++: & or ()?

Tags: c++

Provided that `texts` is an array of 3 strings, what's the difference between `&texts[3]` and `(&texts)[3]`?

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. "an array of 3 strings" could be many things

Comment: C question, but C and C++ are close enough here for [What's the difference between array and &array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194630/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-array) to be good reading.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @user4581301 Not sure that your suggested 'dupe' actually addresses the difference in the `[3]` operation on the two *different* pointer types.

Comment: @AdrianMole Not a dupe or I would have closed the question. Just useful reading. The answer can be inferred from the reading, though.

Comment: Both won't work as both values point at locations that are not part of memory you allocated. `&texts[3]` is a pointer to the element past the end of the array which could be useful in some cases, but you shouldn't dereference it, the other one treats `texts` as the first element of a array of arrays of strings and accesses the fourth of those.

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` subscript operator has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `&` address-of operator.

`&texts[3]` is the same as `&(texts[3])`, meaning the 4th element of the array is accessed and then the address of that element is taken.  Assuming the array is like `string texts[3]`, that will produce a `string*` pointer that is pointing at the 1-past-the-end element of the array, ie similar to an `end` iterator in a `std::array` or `std::vector`.

```
----------------------------
| string | string | string |
----------------------------
                           ^
                        &texts[3]
```

`(&texts)[3]`, on the other hand, takes the address of the array itself, producing a `string(*)[3]` pointer, and then increments that pointer by 3 whole `string[3]` arrays.  So, again assuming `string texts[3]`, you have a `string(*)[3]` pointer that is WAY beyond the end boundary of the array.

```
---------------------------- ---------------------------- ----------------------------
| string | string | string | | string | string | string | | string | string | string |
---------------------------- ---------------------------- ----------------------------
                           ^                                                         ^
                        &texts[3]                                               (&texts)[3]
```